# Failed to install mysql server through Installshield (mysql-installer Information: 10 : MySQL Server 5.6.21's change state request failed)

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, installshield, installscript

I am trying to install the MySQL server and Connector/C++ through Installshield (Installscript) by executing MySQLInstallerConsole.exe with following argument,

"community install server;5.6.21;x64:*:port=3306;openfirewall=true;passwd=root, c++;1.1.4;x64 -silent"

[MySQL Installation fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsqxj.png)

It just runs through the install process without any problem however, nothing is installed and the log file gives following error for each install package:

mysql-installer Information: 10 : MySQL Server 5.6.21's change state request failed.
mysql-installer Information: 10 : Connector/C++ 1.1.4's change state request failed.

When I use the above argument through command prompt manually, it works fine,
[MySQL Installation success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpeHw.png)

Anyone know, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.

My Installshield project type is 'Basic MSI Project'. I can't able to fully install the Server and Connector/C++ through prerequisite. So, I am trying to install the MySQL Server and Connector/C++ through function in Installscript.

After the Script ready, we need to mention, when the function should call. We can set this in 'Custom Actions and Sequences'.

Previously am calling this script 'After InstallFinelize' for 'Install Exec Sequence', so the error occurred.

Once I set the 'After CostInitialize' for 'Install UI Sequence', its working fine and MySQL server, Connector/C++ are installed successfully.